# MFMailComposeViewController: toRecepients Methods Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, mfmailcomposer

I have created a simple email sender using `MFMailComposeViewController`. I programmed it such a way that people will have a textField to fill up a mail address before `MFMailComposeViewController` is called.

When I tried to pass the content of the text field in to the

```
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:receipient];
```

method (recipient is a `NSString`), somehow, when the `MFMailComposViewController` is presented, it always gives

```
Error:"Is not a valid email address"
```

and leaves the Recipient part empty.

If I change

```
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:receipient];
```

to

```
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@app.com"];
```

where I entered the address manually, it will work properly.

Anyone knows how do I do such that I can pass in an `NSString` variable without getting the invalid error?

PS:I did email validation, i have printed out the text as well to double check, the `NSString` is indeed "support@app.com", the same thing as i manually entered, but it just doesn't work.

For those who have tried `MessageUI`, please help to double check if i am making any silly mistakes

Thanks

Regards

Comment: show the code of how you convert textfield string to object ?

Comment: what is recipient ? a string? an object ?

Comment: please dont add one or two lines of code. Add how you are calling the mail composer and when you are accessign the text field text

Comment: when are you calling the mail composer ? Right after you enter the text ? or do you call it on abutton click?

Comment: @Mr.T I am sorry if i was a little harsh to you, rest of it i do not want to explain. See you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine. Try using `arrayWIthObjects` instead of `arraywithObject`:

```
  NSString *recipient =textField.text;
   NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];
```

Use nil, after the recipient, and see if it works or not.